# How to check if email exsit in database with yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, axios, response, yup

I want to check if email exist in database. I wrote something like this, but I have no idea how to pass the result from axios.

```
email: yup
  .string()
  .email('type correct email')
  .required('email is required')
  .test(
    'email check',
    'email exists in the database', 
    async (value) => {
    await AuthServices.checkEmailExist(value).then((response) => {  
    console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
```

My response.data return true if email exist or false if the email is not in the database. How to tell yup if the response is true or false?

Answer (score 0):

All tests must provide a name, an error message, and a validation function that must return true when the current value is valid and false or a ValidationError otherwise. To make a test async, return a promise that resolves true, false, or a ValidationError.

As such, you could try:

```
email: yup
  .string()
  .email('type correct email')
  .required('email is required')
  .test("email check", "email exists in the database", async value => {
        (await AuthServices.checkEmailExist(value).data) === "true";
    })
```